# Why am I getting mongo db reference error when the db clearly is existing?

Tags: mongodb

I see the db that I created and switch to it. Then I'd like to show its entries but receive the following error:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
szdb    0.000GB
> use szdb
switched to db szdb
> show collections
Municipalities
> szdb.Municipalities.find()
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: szdb is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

you refer to the current db as simply `db`:

```
use szdb
db.Municipalities.find()
```